# (To prevent Memory Error)How to one hot encode word list to a matrix of INTEGER 8 in Keras using Tokenize class

Tags: python, text, keras, nltk, tokenize

AS FLOAT64 takes more memory,which is the default data type of the tokenized matrix,I want it to be in INT8 ,thus saving space.

[link to documentation](https://keras.io/preprocessing/text/)

This is the method I'm talking,

```
texts_to_matrix(texts):
Return: numpy array of shape (len(texts), num_words).
Arguments:
    texts: list of texts to vectorize.
    mode: one of "binary", "count", "tfidf", "freq" (default: "binary").
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Taking a look at the source code, the result matrix is created [here](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/9f8f520767a322165b01303f84943e59be342beb/keras/preprocessing/text.py#L343) using `np.zeros()` with no `dtype` keyword argument which would result in `dtype` being set to default value set in [function definition](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.zeros.html) which is `float`. I think the choice of this data type is made to support all forms of transformation like `tfidf` which results in non-integer output. 
So I think you have to options:

**1. Change the source code**
You can change add a keyword argument to definition of `texts_to_matrix` like `dtype` and change [the line](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/9f8f520767a322165b01303f84943e59be342beb/keras/preprocessing/text.py#L343) where matrix is created to

```
x = np.zeros((len(sequences), num_words), dtype=dtype)
```

**2.Use another tool for preprocessing:**
You can preprocess your text using another tool and then feed it to keras network. For example you can use scikit learn's [CountVectorizer](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.feature_extraction.text.CountVectorizer.html) like:

```
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer
cv = CountVectorizer(dtype=np.int8, ...)
matrix = cv.fit_transform(texts).toarray()
```

Comment: But this works only on my local machine. I run my models in Google COLAB so how to modify this file there?

Comment: @ShashiTunga I dont think it would be straight forward to change the source code on Google Colab, so I recommend you subclass  `keras.preprocessing.text.tokenizer` in your code (and keep the name to `Tokenizer` so the wont be any need to change other codes) and apply modifications you want in your sublcass and use that instead.